# Error while configuring Qt Creator 2.6 beta with BlackBerry NDK

Tags: qt, qt-creator, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I am facing a problem configuring Qt Creator, unable to add Qt Version.
Error is shown below :

[image: Problem Reported]

I had installed Cascades native NDK and the BB simulator.

Help me out of this problem....

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using Windows. So all next is context depended on Windows.

You need to add special environment variables like these:

```
QNX_TARGET=C:/Development/bb-ndk-3.0/target_10_0_9_386/qnx6
QNX_HOST=C:/Development/bb-ndk-3.0/host_10_0_9_52/win32/x86
QNX_CONFIGURATION=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Native SDK
MAKEFLAGS=-I%QNX_TARGET%/usr/include
PATH=%QNX_HOST%\usr\bin;%QNX_CONFIGURATION%\bin;C:\Development\bb-ndk-3.0\ide\win32\x86\eclipse\jre\bin;%PATH%
PYTHONPATH=
QDE=C:\Development\bb-ndk-3.0\ide\win32\x86
```

or run `bbndk-env.bat` before starting **Qt Creator**:

1. Copy `bbndk-env.bat` to bin folder for QtCreator
2. Rename it to start-qtcreator.bat
3. Add there line `qtcreator.exe`
4. Run bat instead qtcreator

Comment: i have executed "bbndk-env.bat", but when i check my enviroment variables, they were not their..

Comment: All instruction i have read upto now was to set the environment variable by executing "bbndk-env.bat", i also executed all this commands as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have done as per your updated answer, now error spoted is different than the previous one and that is "No qml Viewer installed".
[image]

Comment: i just want to know that , why this "bbndk-env.bat" is unable to set the path.i have executed it many times but still no variables are set .